# Can I use my Raspberry Pi Zero's 5V to power a motor driver?

Tags: dc-motor

I have a L9110 motor driver board that I am using to power a motor from my Raspberry Pi. Can I use the Raspberry Pi's 5V output to power the motor driver?

Answer (score 1):

The Pi Zero has minimal (i.e. NONE) power circuitry.
The 5V output is directly connected to the 5V input - so (unless you are drawing so much power it melts the PC board traces) it will output whatever you input.